# Yii issue while moving from windows to linux

Tags: php, yii

I do several yii 1.1 projects on ubuntu then host it on linux servers. But when i download these projects on wamp it does not work.

In our views I have put code like this

```
 <img src="<? echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/"></img>
```

and when i run it on windows wamp, the php is not executed and baseurl part is sent to browser without getting executed and the whole site does not display. Why is this happening?

I have set the path and other settings..... Even on windows system where I am able to use yiic.bat to create and run news projects, projects created on linux does not work... But new projects created using yiic.bat works.

Comment: Have you tried some pure php code?  Try to use something like `echo "test"` for testing php. Probably this problem is related to php, not yii.

Comment: Show tag <? should be replaced to <?php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely is that you are using a newer version of PHP where short tags `<?` or not accepted by PHP, instead you need to use the full opening tag `<?php`.

If you'd like to allow short tags you can add this to your php.ini file

```
short_open_tag=On
```

Comment: thanks for this great tip...i was using open tags on my views....i will check and let you know if this fixes the issue...

Comment: you were right...i added that and it flies.. i have marked yours as right answer